Equivalent of one-tailed Fisher's exact test for enrichment of the diagonal in 3x3 contingency table?
I have 2 ordinal variables A and B with 3 levels each (e.g. "down", "no change", and "up"). I want to know whether the up/down changes indicated by A and B are consistent with each other. That is, my alternative hypothesis is that if A is "up", then B is also more likely than random chance to be "up", and same for "down". If the levels were just "change" and "no change", I would make the 2x2 contingency table and perform a one-tailed Fisher's exact test with the alternative hypothesis that the odds ratio is greater than 1, i.e. I would test whether the diagonal entries of the 2x2 contingency matrix are greater than expected by random change. I would like to perform the analogous test for enrichment of the diagonal of my 3x3 contingency table, but I have not been able to find a suitable test. The extensions I've seen of Fisher's exact test to 3x3 tables don't specify how to test a specific alternative hypothesis. They just test the null hypothesis of the two variables being independent against any form of dependence between them. Is there such a test? Alternatively, is "enrichment of the diagonal" the wrong way to conceptualize this?

I may be muisunderstanding, but from your description, it would seem that A & B are 2 measures of the same "unit" (subject, condition, etc.). So the 2 measures are paired? ANd then you want to know when they "agree" (both "up", both "down", or, I would assume both "no change (NC)"? Can you clarify if this is really the case? If that were to be the case, just look at all the "pairs", classify them as Y/N (for agreement), and you have a simple binomial test: do you have significantly more than 50% Y(es, they agree). And it can be a single-sided test (Y>N).

@jginestet Yes, they are paried. You can think of A and B as two columns in a table with many rows, each row being an observation. A and B can each be -1, 0, or 1. And yeah, I want to know if they match more than random chance. Checking for significantly more than 50% agreement is no good, because if A & B are both 99% NC, then they will agree way more than 50% by random chance even if they are independent.

It is up to you to decide how to handle the cases where one or both are "NC". That depends on exactly A and B are measuring, etc. Or you could to exclude the cases where both are NC, or? The key point is that you do not want to analyze A & B independently, but only the "difference" (because thh data is paired). Then decide what is agreement/disagreement, and test if the agree/disagree proportions are similar, or not... The point is that you do not have a 2x3 scenario, but a 1x2 (or maybe 1x3) scenario.  Binomial test

@jginestet I mean, A and B could also both be 99% "up", and the same issue would exist. The null hypothesis for this binomial test would depend on the margins.

Unless I am missing something, it seems that it is not so much that A & B both say "up" X% of the time. It is that for X% of the rows, A and B "agree". Not the same thing.  In you example, if A & B have "up" for 90% of the rows, they agree, and you have made your point. Now, this could be because the questions, and the related A & B measures are trivially non-informative.  Not the fault of the binomial test, just the fault of the study. Or in fact, the finding that A & B agree for 90% of the units, and always in the "up" direction, is a very interesting finding. Can you clarify your null?

@Ryan maybe you could use an association measure like kendall's tau-b. The idea of concordant vs. discordant pairs seems in line with what you want. Not exactly but still ...

@Ryan also Cohen's kappa for inter-rater reliability could be appropriate.

@BenP I considered Cohen's kappa, but if I understand correctly, it is designed for arbitrary categorical variables and does not take into account the fact that a variable is ordinal. However, perhaps it is equally valid for ordinal variables? I wasn't able to find a clear statement about this.

@jginestet My null hypothesis is same as Fisher's exact test: that the row margins and column margins of the 3x3 contingency table are independent of each other. However, rather than test for any deviation from independence, I'm looking to test a specific alternative hypothesis, similar to how a one-tailed test works in the 2x2 case. I think the alternative hypothesis can be expressed as: "the diagonal elements are larger than expected under the null, while the off-diagonal elements are smaller than expected". I'm not entirely sure how to formalize that, though.
